# MiniTest Model Validation Test Failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, minitest

I have a model 'Policy'. Within that model, I have presence validations for policy_holder and premium_amount. I'm attempting to write a MiniTest test for this model. For some reason, my tests are failing.

Here is my model:

```
class Policy < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :industry
  belongs_to :carrier
  belongs_to :agent

  validates :policy_holder,  presence: true
  validates :premium_amount, presence: true
end
```

And here are my tests:

```
require 'test_helper'

class PolicyTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test 'should validate policy holder is present' do
    policy = Policy.find_or_create_by(policy_holder: nil, premium_amount: '123.45',
                                      industry_id: 1, carrier_id: 1,
                                      agent_id: 1)
    assert_not policy.valid?
  end

  test 'should validate premium amount is present' do
    policy = Policy.find_or_create_by(policy_holder: 'Bob Stevens', premium_amount: nil,
                                      industry_id: 1, carrier_id: 1,
                                      agent_id: 1)
    assert_not policy.valid?
  end

  test 'should be valid when both policy holder and premium amount are present' do
    policy = Policy.find_or_create_by(policy_holder: 'Bob Stevens', premium_amount: '123.45',
                                      industry_id: 1, carrier_id: 1,
                                      agent_id: 1)
    assert policy.valid?
  end
end
```

Here is the failure message:

```
Failure:
PolicyTest#test_should_be_valid_when_both_policy_holder_and_premium_amount_are_present [test/models/policy_test.rb:22]:
Expected false to be truthy.
```

The last test is failing when I believe is should be passing. This has me thinking that my other tests are not correct either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a much easier way to test validations with less "carpet bombing" involved:

```
require 'test_helper'

class PolicyTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase 
  setup do
    @policy = Policy.new
  end

  test "should validate presence of policy holder" do
    @policy.valid? # triggers the validations
    assert_includes(
      @policy.errors.details[:policy_holder],
      { error: :blank }
    )
  end

  # ...
end
```

This tests just that validation and not every validation on the model combined.  Using `assert policy.valid?` will not tell you anything about what failed in the error message.

`errors.details` was added in Rails 5. In older versions you need to use:

```
assert_includes( policy.errors[:premium_amount], "can't be blank" )
```

Which tests against the actual error message. Or you can use [active_model-errors_details](https://github.com/cowbell/active_model-errors_details) which backports the feature.

Answer (score 0):

So what's happening here is the validations are failing on the model.

`.valid?` will return `true` if there are no errors on the object when the validations are run.

Since you are clearly seeing a "false", that means one or more of the validations on the model are failing.

In a Rails console, you should try creating an object manually and casting it to a variable, then testing it to see the errors thusly:

```
test = Policy.new(whatever params are needed to initialize here)
# This will give you the object

test.valid?
#This will likely return FALSE, and NOW you can run:

test.errors
#This will actually show you where the validation failed inside the object
```

Regardless, this is almost assuredly a problem in the model and its creation.

Keep in mind, `.errors` won't work until AFTER you run `.valid?` on the object.

Comment: @hashrocket can you paste your schema for the Policy?  Could it be as simple as the premium amount should be a float instead of a string?